# How PhpStorm setting to use COMPACTED Allman same line after open braces style

Tags: ide, phpstorm, code-formatting, jetbrains-ide

I want the PHP format to stop putting a newline after the open left brace for classes,functions,if,do,while,for,foreach.

```
class Foo
{   var    $numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
    const FIRST  = 'first';
    const Z      = -1;

    function bar($v, $w = "a")
    {   $y      = $w;
        if(true)
        {   $y = 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see there's no such option. You can submit this as a feature request to JetBrains issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Thank you, I've submitted this feature request.